# Row and ColumnHeader, CellMouseClick event vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have code on vb.net which is checking radiobutton3 whenever a cell has clicked. But it also works when columnheader or rowheader clicked. How i can make this code inaccesable for columheader and rowheader click?

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView1.CellMouseClick
        RadioButton3.Checked = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: You can check `e.RowIndex <> -1` and `e.ColumnIndex <> -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView1.MouseDown
    Dim ht As DataGridView.HitTestInfo
    ht = Me.MyDataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If ht.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
        RadioButton3.Checked = True
        cont()
    End If
End Sub
```

This link helped:
[context menu for datagridview cell, rowheader and columnheader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761320/context-menu-for-datagridview-cell-rowheader-and-columnheader)

Answer (score 0):

e.RowIndex=-1 represents the row header.
e.ColumnIndex=-1 represents the column header.

You can check as following:

```
Private Sub shipmentDetailsDataGridView_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

    RadioButton3.Checked = e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0

End Sub
```